# Overriding getters and setters for attributes from a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

The aim is to provide some strings in a list as attributes of a class. The class shall have not only attributes, but also the respective getter and setter methods. In some other class inherited from that some of those setters need to be overridden.

To this end I came up with the following. Using `setattr` in a loop over the list of strings, an attribute and the respective methods are created. Concerning this first part, the code works as expected.
However I am not able to override the setters in an inheriting class.

```
class Base():
    attributes = ["attr{}".format(i) for i in range(100)]

    def __init__(self):
        _get = lambda a: lambda : getattr(self, a)
        _set = lambda a: lambda v: setattr(self, a, v)

        for attr in self.attributes:
            setattr(self, attr, None)
            setattr(self, "get_"+attr, _get(attr))
            setattr(self, "set_"+attr, _set(attr))


class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #setattr(self, "set_attr4", set_attr4)

    # Here I want to override one of the setters to perform typechecking
    def set_attr4(self, v):
        print("This being printed would probably solve the problem.")
        if type(v) == bool:
            super().set_attr4(v)
        else:
            raise ValueError("attr4 must be a boolean")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  b = Base()
  b.attr2 = 5
  print(b.get_attr2())
  b.set_attr3(55)
  print(b.get_attr3())

  c = Child()
  c.set_attr4("SomeString")
  print(c.get_attr4())
```

The output here is

```
5
555
SomeString
```

The expected output would however be

```
5
555
This being printed would probably solve the problem.
ValueError("attr4 must be a boolean")
```

So somehow the `set_attr4` method is never called; which I guess is expected, because `__init__` is called after the class structure is read in. But I am at loss on how else to override those methods. I tried to add `setattr(self, "set_attr4", set_attr4)` (the commented line in the code above) but to no avail.

Or more generally, there is the `propery` which is usually used for creating getters and setters. But I don't think I understand how to apply it in a case where the getters and setters are created dynamically and need to be overridden by a child.

Is there any solution to this?

---

Update due to comments: It was pointed out by several people that using getters/setters in python may not be a good style and that they may usually not be needed. While this is definitely something to keep in mind, the background of this question is that I'm extending an old existing code which uses getters/setters throughout. I hence do not wish to change the style and let the user (this project only has some 20 users in total, but still...) suddenly change the way they access properties within the API.
However any future reader of this may consider that the getter/setter approach is at least questionable.

Comment: Why create getters and setters at *all*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the question with the reason I do want to use getters/setters here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metaclasses to the rescue!

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        for attr in cls.attributes:
            if not hasattr(cls, attr):
                setattr(cls, attr, None)
                setattr(cls, f'get_{attr}', cls._get(attr))
                setattr(cls, f'set_{attr}', cls._set(attr))

class Base(metaclass=Meta):
    attributes = ["attr{}".format(i) for i in range(100)]

    _get = lambda a: lambda self: getattr(self, a)
    _set = lambda a: lambda self, v: setattr(self, a, v)

# the rest of your code goes here
```

This is pretty self-explanatory: make `attributes, _get, _set` class variables (so that you can access them without class instantiation), then let the metaclass set everything up for you.

Comment: I'm accepting this solution because it is pretty compact and directly applicable to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `__init__` is executed after the subclass is created, so it overrides what was specified there.

The minimal change needed to fix the problem is to check whether the attribute has already been set:

```
class Base():
    attributes = ["attr{}".format(i) for i in range(100)]

    def __init__(self):
        _get = lambda a: lambda : getattr(self, a)
        _set = lambda a: lambda v: setattr(self, a, v)

        for attr in self.attributes:
            setattr(self, attr, None)
            if not hasattr(self, "get_"+attr):
                setattr(self, "get_"+attr, _get(attr))
            if not hasattr(self, "set_"+attr):
                setattr(self, "set_"+attr, _set(attr))
```

However, I do not see to point in doing that this way. This is creating a new getter and setter **for each instance** of `Base`. I would instead rather create them on the class. That can be done with a class decorator, or with a metaclass, or in the body of the class itself, or in some other way.

For example, this is ugly, but simple:

```
class Base():
    attributes = ["attr{}".format(i) for i in range(100)]

    for attr in attributes:
        exec(f"get_{attr} = lambda self: self.{attr}")
        exec(f"set_{attr} = lambda self, value: setattr(self, '{attr}', value)")
    del attr
```

This is better:

```
class Base:
    pass

attributes = ["attr{}".format(i) for i in range(100)]

for attr in attributes:
    setattr(Base, f"get_{attr}", lambda self: getattr(self, attr))
    setattr(Base, f"set_{attr}", lambda self, value: setattr(self, '{attr}', value))
```

Comment: Yes, that's an option. But it would allow me to override the method, i.e. `super().set_attr4(v)` does not work. In the limit, I could change this to perform the setting by itself, though. If nothing better comes up, that's a workaround.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest a lot of things aren't going to work, you aren't creating methods, you are simply putting attributes on each instance which happen to be functions. To be proper methods, you need to set them *on the class object*

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're creating the "methods" in the instance of the `Base` class (`__init__` only runs in the instance).

Inheriting happens before you instance your class, and won't look into instances.

In other words, When you try to override the method, it wasn't even created in first place.

A solution is to create them **in the class** and not in `self` instance inside `__init__`:

```
def _create_getter(attr):
    def _get(self): 
        return getattr(self, attr)
    return _get

def _create_setter(attr):    
    def _set(self, value): 
        return setattr(self, attr, value)
    return _set    


class Base():
    attributes = ["attr{}".format(i) for i in range(100)]

for attr in Base.attributes:
    setattr(Base, 'get_' + attr, _create_getter(attr))
    setattr(Base, 'set_' + attr, _create_setter(attr))
```

Then inheriting will work normally:

```
class Child(Base):
    def set_attr4(self, v):
        print("This being printed would probably solve the problem.")
        if type(v) == bool:
            super().set_attr4(v)
        else:
            raise ValueError("attr4 must be a boolean")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  b = Base()
  b.attr2 = 5
  print(b.get_attr2())
  b.set_attr3(55)
  print(b.get_attr3())

  c = Child()
  c.set_attr4("SomeString")
  print(c.get_attr4())
```

You could also just not do it - make your `Base` class as normal, and make setters only for the attributes you want, in the child class:

```
class Base:
    pass

class Child(Base):
    @property
    def attr4(self):
        return self._attr4

    @attr4.setter
    def attr4(self, new_v):
        if not isinstance(new_v, bool):
            raise TypeError('Not bool')
        self._attr4 = new_v
```

Testing:

```
c = Child()

c.attr3 = 2 # works fine even without any setter
c.attr4 = True #works fine, runs the setter
c.attr4 = 3 #type error
```

Comment: This should work, but it seems odd to externally supply the methods. So is creating the attributes outside the class a common practice?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest dynamically creating setters and getters is not a common practice. Heck, even using getters and setters is not common! This is not java, you only create properties when really needed. Getters that do nothing and just return the attribute are frowned upon.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the entire idea feels uncommon and sounds like overengineering.

Comment: Yeah, I do need *some* setters. But having them for only some of the properties, but not all would result in a confusing API.

Comment: You don't need setters in python - you can use properties - they call a function when attribute is set. Instead of `x.set_foo(5)` your API users can just do `x.foo = 5` and it will call your method anyway - and you can do it only for the attributes that need it

Comment: Mhh, ok, I will keep that in mind for the next time I write some API from scratch. It doesn't help for my specific use case though. However, feel free to update the answer with how you would recommend this to work with `property`s.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added example of how to override a setter in a child class, without needing to create setters and getters in the parent.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you *don't even need properties* if all  your setter is doing is `self.x = val`, then just use `my_object.x = val`, a property would only be required when you decide to refactor your code to actually do something in the setter, allowing you to transparently do, say, validation while keeping the `my_object.x = val` syntax without breaking downstream code, it's how Python does encapsulation

Comment: For this code I get an error `AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'attr4'` triggered in the line `print(c.get_attr4())`. However I would expect to get a `ValueError` from the line before that.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the problem. The creation of your `Base` instance happens after the `Child` class defines `set_attr4`. Since `Base` is creating it's getters/setters dynamically, it just blasts over `Child`s version upon creation.

One alternative way (in addition to the other answers) is to create the `Child`'s getters/setters dynamically too. The idea here is to go for "convention over configuration" and just prefix methods you want to override with `override_`. Here's an example:

```
class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        overrides = [override for override in dir(self) if override.startswith("override_")]
        for override in overrides:
            base_name = override.split("override_")[-1]
            setattr(self, base_name, getattr(self, override))


    # Here I want to override one of the setters to perform typechecking
    def override_set_attr4(self, v):
        print("This being printed would probably solve the problem.")
        if type(v) == bool:
            super().set_attr4(v)
        else:
            raise ValueError("attr4 must be a boolean") # Added "raise" to this, overwise we just return None...
```

which outputs:

```
5
55
This being printed would probably solve the problem.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\stack.py", line 39, in <module>
    c.set_attr4("SomeString")
  File ".\stack.py", line 29, in override_set_attr4
    raise ValueError("attr4 must be a boolean") # Added "raise" to this, overwise we just return None...
ValueError: attr4 must be a boolean
```

**Advantages** here are that the `Base` doesn't have to know about the `Child` class. In the other answers, there's very subtle `Base`/`Child` coupling going on. It also might not be desirable to touch the `Base` class *at all* (violation of the Open/Closed principle).

**Disadvantages** are that "convention over configuration" to avoid a true inheritance mechanism is a bit clunky and unintuitive. The `override_` function is also still hanging around on the `Child` instance (which you may or may not care about).

I think the real problem here is that you're trying to define getters and setters in such a fashion. We usually don't even want getters/setters in Python. This definitely *feels* like an X/Y problem, but maybe it isn't. You have a lot of rep, so I'm not going to give you some pedantic spiel about it. Even so, maybe take a step back and think about what you're really trying to do and consider alternatives.

Comment: This is an interesting workaround. Because you mention it, I don't think it's an XY problem, because I really do want to use getters and setters due to compatibility with the code base I'm extending. It may be that some years ago, someone should have asked this question before writing that code though. I learned programming with Java so those getters seemed quite natural to me. Concerning rep, that shouldn't matter when asking or answering a question, I guess; but it's obvious that I did not get the python gold batch from answering core python questions ;-).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest If it's a legacy issue, I feel your pain. I've gone through all sorts of nonsense to make legacy code work or be more performant. And with legacy baselines, since most of them are operational (else we would have thrown it away, right?), it always feels like everything was supposed to be done *yesterday*. Best of luck, and interesting question.